# Get an overlay or placeholder on pause using autoplay on Hover HTML Video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, html5-video

I have a question please I got an HTML playing video on hover but once I go away with the mouse I got a hide video function, what I try to do is once I leave the mouse from the playing video to show the placeholder image again something like an Overlay on top of the video. I hope someone can please help me with this.

Here is a live example of the code https://jsfiddle.net/the_nexi/514pwkeo/2/

Thanks in advance

```js
       $(document).ready(function() {       
            $('.video').each(function(i, obj) {
                $(this).on("mouseover", function() { hoverVideo(i); });
                $(this).on("mouseout", function() { hideVideo(i); });
            });
    });

    function hoverVideo(i) {  
            $('.thevideo')[i].play(); 
    }

    function hideVideo(i) {
            $('.thevideo')[i].currentTime = 0; 
            $('.thevideo')[i].pause();
    }
```

```css
*{font-family: sans-serif}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>If you hover over this Thumbnail the Video will start but once you move the mouse away from the image the Thumbnail (Poster) should appear again with an Overlay this is what I try to do.</p>
<div class="video">
    <video class="thevideo" loop muted preload="auto" poster="https://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/bbb-splash.png?x11217">
        <source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39204677/show-the-poster-after-pausing-the-video-in-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.video').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(this).on("mouseover", hoverVideo);
    $(this).on("mouseout", hideVideo);
  });
});

function hoverVideo() {
  $(this).find(".overlayImage").hide();
  $(this).find(".thevideo")[0].play();
}

function hideVideo(video) {
  $(this).find(".thevideo")[0].currentTime = 0;
  $(this).find(".thevideo")[0].pause();
  $(this).find(".overlayImage").show();
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif
}

.video {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
}

.overlayImage {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="video">
  <img src="https://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/bbb-splash.png?x11217" class="overlayImage" width="320" />
  <video class="thevideo" loop muted poster="https://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/bbb-splash.png?x11217">
        <source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>

<div class="video">
  <img src="http://hdwarena.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Beautiful-Wallpaper.jpg" class="overlayImage" width="320" />
  <video class="thevideo" loop muted poster="https://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/bbb-splash.png?x11217">
        <source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>


<div class="video">
  <img src="https://d2v9y0dukr6mq2.cloudfront.net/video/thumbnail/rWaXO67Bipm9mgo7/videoblocks-4k-footage-disco-lights-as-an-abstract-colored-animated-background-or-wallpaper-light-leaks_sl5jole0z_thumbnail-small01.jpg" class="overlayImage" width="320" />
  <video class="thevideo" loop muted poster="https://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/bbb-splash.png?x11217">
        <source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>

<div class="video">
  <img src="https://d2v9y0dukr6mq2.cloudfront.net/video/thumbnail/BxWKHw2nWj8nx9c2x/videoblocks-red-wallpaper-slider_rxlvi6ltb_thumbnail-small11.jpg" class="overlayImage" width="320" />
  <video class="thevideo" loop muted poster="https://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/bbb-splash.png?x11217">
        <source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

In this, every video is separate from each other, allow me to explain why:

1. I changed the way you set the functions for the events `mouseover` and `mouseout` and now they are event functions.
2. Inside the functions `hoverVideo()` and `hideVideo()`, we hide the image and play the video using `$(this)` which is passed through the [`$.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as the correspondent video div and find the elements (video and image) with [`$.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
3. **Optional**: *I added the width:320px in the css because it was somewhat annoying that it continued playing the video outside of the video because of the bigger width.*

If you want you can get rid of the class tags, and use the [`$.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) function like this, for example:

```
$(this).find("video")[0].currentTime = 0;
$(this).find("video")[0].pause();
$(this).find("img").show();
```

In this way it will find every `video` element inside the `div` with the `.video` class and do the rest from there, the same for `img`.

I hope this code helps you.

Comment: Thanks so much just got one more question, I want to disable the video hover on mobile phones to save network bandwidth for people on the phone. I tried adding this code https://jsfiddle.net/the_nexi/vzzkqfo1/3/ but once I open up the dev tools it says the video got still downloaded but not displayed hope you can help me with this too so on the phone it doesn't download the video. I'm learning JS and that would help me a lot if you know how to prevent downloading it on mobile size. 

I also accepted now your reply and highly appreciate your help and very detailed explanation of how it works.

Comment: Could you try to use the [preload](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_preload.asp) attribute on the videos? This make it so that the video doesn't load on startup

Answer (score 1):

```js
            $(document).ready(function() {       
   $('.video').each(function(i, obj) {
     $(this).on("mouseover", function() { hoverVideo(i); $(this).find(".overlayImage").hide(); });
     $(this).on("mouseout", function() { hideVideo(i); $(this).find(".overlayImage").show(); });
   });
});
function hoverVideo(i) {       
 $('.thevideo')[i].play();             
}
function hideVideo(i) {
  $('.thevideo')[i].currentTime = 0; 
  $('.thevideo')[i].pause();
}
```

```css
*{font-family: sans-serif}
.video {
  position:relative;
}
.overlayImage {
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="video">
  <img src="https://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/bbb-splash.png?x11217" class="overlayImage" width="320" />
    <video class="thevideo" loop muted poster="https://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/bbb-splash.png?x11217">
        <source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

I hope this updated code help you

Comment: Thanks so much :) You're amazing! I appreciate your help a lot

Comment: I noticed a very small bug when I have more than 1 of video with this code and hover over the second video it affects also the first video overlay here is a code example https://jsfiddle.net/the_nexi/z5sw2k5n/ hope you can help me fixing it, please